# Simple CSS Floating Extra Space

Tags: html, css, css-float

At this link:
http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction18.htm

If you go into the DOM manipulation and turn off the black border of `.containingbox`, you'll see that the `<p>` element goes right back to where it should be floated next to the square. I understand that because of the border of `.containingbox` the `<p>` element may be pushed down a little, but it seems to be putting pushed down to the point where I'm not understanding something.

Just want a little insight and to fully understand this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no border on `.contaningbox`, the margins of h1 and p elements collapse. You can read more about [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

[image]

*Yellow area shows the margin here.*

p element has a default margin on user agent stylesheet. If you zero out the margin, the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to margin collapsing.  If you add the following it fill fix the issue

```
p.highlight {
    margin: 0; /* Added this */
    padding: 0 /* Added this */
    border: 5px solid #aaa;
}
```